# PHP: Opening url from database using header

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am pretty new to php (mostly don't do web development at all actually) and, have gotten into it lately. I am trying to make a login page that redirects users after login to a unique URL linked to the user. So I wanted to have say 4 columns in the database: id, username, password, and redirect. And after a successful login to have the URL redirect to the redirect column in the db that is storing the user URL. The problem is the code that I have been working off of. To make a login I cant seem to have it redirect to the db column using the header("location:) line. Here is my code maybe you guys can kindly help me:

```
<?php
$host="sql1om"; // Host name 
$username="b33_1033"; // Mysql username 
$password="b33_1033"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

So I can't figure out how to add a db column variable to output the url from the redirect column in the

```
header("location:login_success.php);
```

Every time I try a variable in that line nothing happens
Any help would be appreciated. Please thoroughly explain I am a newbie at php. Thank-you!

Here is edited code that I got working (with help):

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file"login_success.php"
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT redirect FROM members");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   header("Location: " . $row['redirect']);
}
exit();
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch your results into an associative array:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

Then simply use `header("Location: $row['redirect']");`

- Enclosing a string in double quotes enable you to insert a variable in there.
- Alternatively, you can also concatentate: `header("Location: " . $row['redirect']);`
- Your SQL results will be stored in an associatively array called `$row`. To access the `redirect` column, use `$row['redirect']`. Of course, `$row` will only be populated if a row or rows are found.
- Finally, it is good practice to have an `exit()` to immediate stop script execution if you are redirecting.

Your code would look like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row 
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row 
if($count==1){ 

   // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php" 
   $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
   $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   header("Location: $row['redirect']");
   exit();
}else { 
   echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I tried adding the var. in the script and no redirection takes place after entering of correct user and password. Do I need to add anything else to the script besides the $result['redirect'] line??? Thanks

Comment: @user1232264: did you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`? `$result` only points to a SQL resource. You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to retrieve the values into an associative array.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but, where would I put that in the file? Thank you again for all the great help.

Comment: Thanks, it displays the login succesful page as normal but, when I add the two lines for the db and type in the correct user information the page is left blank.... darn.

Comment: @user1232264: Could you update your question with the full code you are using now?

Comment: I think your use of `session_register` (which is a deprecated method) throws up a notice which messes up the redirect. please see my updated code.

Comment: Did you add the `exit();` statement after the redirect? Try turning on by adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the beginning of the code and see if it throws out any errors.

Comment: I added the exit() to it, yes. I put the ini_set code at the beginning one line under the first <?php and, tried it and the page displays nothing.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong do you know of a script that works that I can use?

Comment: I just tested a stripped down version of your code here and it works fine. There is a posibility that the redirect url is not avaliable in your current path. For example, if you are redirecting to `test.php`, and the login page is at `http://site.com/login.php`, `test.php` needs to be in `http://site.com/test.php`. As a test, try redirecting to `http://google.com` to ensure that everything else works.

Comment: If I replace the header("location: $row['redirect'].  with header("location: http://google.com"); It redirects too the google homepage as the $row['redirect']" just shows a blank page. In my db I have a column name redirect inside my test database. I am trying to get my test login to have a seperate url for each user.

Comment: Inside my redirect column I have the google address also and, it still gives a blank page.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I finally got it working! I'll update the code to what I have know that is working. I appreciate it so much! :)